# cómo explicarían la funcion void?

Tags: c

Sé que se utiliza la función void mayormente cuando se interactúa con el usuario, pero no entiendo cuando dicen que no devuelve nada(?, y osea cuando no se usaría?

Comment: Tengo una respuesta. Pero antes, recuerda aceptar las respuestas que te dan. Y cuentame que investigaste respecto a esto (porque hasta wikipedia tiene una definición para esto)

Comment: Es específicamente eso. Cuando utilizas funciones estas tienen la posibilidad de regresar algo. Un numero, una cadena, un arreglo, etc. Cuando no regresan nada son funciones que no tienen un retorno o regresan un valor vació. Esto simplemente y sencillamente no afecta el ciclo de ejecución.

Answer (score 3):

El tipo `void` es un tipo de C que en esencia significa "cualquier tipo", y no "vacio" (aunque su traducción del ingles sea esa)

Normalmente se aplica cuando una función no va a devolver ningún valor (no tiene un return), como en los ejemplos que te han explicado aqui. Sin embargo, es posible hacer un return con una funcion que tiene un tipo void de resultado. Concretamente con el `puntero void`.

Analiza el siguiente caso:

```
void *res devuelve(int value) {
    char palabra[5] = "hola";
    int numero = 10;

    if (value == 1)
        return numero;
    else      
        return palabra;
}
```

En este caso, `void` hace que el valor que se devuelve, sea de uno u otro tipo, en funcion del parametro de la funcion.

Con la función anterior, podemos hacer un codigo como el siguiente:

```
int main() {
    int num;
    char *cad;

    cad = (char *)devuelve(50);
    printf("%s\n", cad);

    num = (int) devuelve(1);
    printf("%c\n", num);
}
```

Esto no se podria hacer si especificamos un tipo distinto (int, char, long...) que devuelve el return en el prototipo de la función. El puntero void sirve para eso.

Por lo tanto, no hay que pensar en `void` como algo nulo, sino mas bien como "cualquier tipo"

Answer (score 1):

La razón para crear una **función** (**método**), es para tener una operación almacenada y poder utilizarla cuando la necesites. Ahora bien, puedes estructurarlas de acuerdo a tus necesidades. Voy a mencionar una de las estructuras, como ejemplo para poder responder a tu pregunta:

1. **Función que recibe y no retorna**: En este caso, la **función** necesariamente tendrá que recibir *parámetros* que serán utilizados para llevar a cabo la tarea, estos *parámetros* son ingresados ya sea por el usuario o definidos "predeterminadamente" por el sistema. Por otra parte **no retornara**, esto quiere decir que la operación no dará como resultado un valor, simplemente realizara la tarea que le hayas asignado, un ejemplo muy sencillo seria el de ejecutar en pantalla un mensaje de acuerdo a los valores que esta recibiendo.

No se si me hice entender.

Cuando veas **Programación Orientada a Objetos** (**POO**), te darás de cuenta de la importancia de estos métodos.

Espero haberte ayudado y te invito a que sigas consultando en la web, seguro encontraras mucho material para aprender. Este articulo tal vez te explique un poco mas.
http://progra.usm.cl/apunte/materia/funciones.html

Answer (score 1):

Toma como ejemplo esta dos funciones.

```
void sumar1(a,b){
    a+b;
}

float sumar2(a,b){
   return a+b;
}
```

La misma funcion, solo que una devuelve un `float` y la otra no devuelve nada(`void`)

`float x = sumar1(2,2);` ***ERROR esta funcion no devuelve NADA***

`float y = sumar2(2,2);` ***Bien! ahora la variable "y" es igual a 4***

Answer (score 1):

Según la definición de Oxford, "*void*" tiene los siguientes significados, he resaltado los relevantes para el tema que tratamos:

> #### adjective
>
> 1. Not valid or legally binding.
> 2. ***Completely empty***.
>
>    2. formal (of an office or position) vacant.
> 3. predicative (in bridge and whist) having been dealt no cards in a particular suit.
>
> #### noun
>
> 1. ***A completely empty space***.
>
>    1. An unfilled space in a wall, building, or other structure.
>    2. ***An emptiness caused by the loss of something***.
> 2. (in bridge and whist) a suit in which a player is dealt no cards.
>
> #### verb [with object]
>
> 1. *North American* Declare that (something) is not valid or legally binding.
> 2. Discharge or drain away (water, gases, etc.).
>
>    2. Medicine Excrete (waste matter).
>    3. usually as adjective "*voided*" Empty or evacuate (a container or space).

"*Void*" significa vacío o ausente. Por eso cuando una función devuelve `void` significa que devuelve nada (el retorno está ausente).

¿En qué casos se usará una función que no devuelve nada?

- Cuando programes una acción de la que no esperas resultado alguno:

  - Abre la puerta `void abrirPuerta();`, vacía el cubo `void vaciarCubo();`, ...

¿En qué casos se usará una función que devuelve algo?

- Cuando programes una acción de la que esperas algún resultado:

  - Preparame un café `cafe prepararCafe();`, dime la hora `hora decirHora();`, ...

Comment: Segun la definicion que pones, significaria "tipo ausente", o para nosotros "que no esta definido el tipo" del resultado de la funcion.

Comment: @Jakala esa definición también es compatible con la explicación ¿no?

Comment: Así, claro. Solo era por aclararlo 